# Jenkins Editable Email Notification Templates

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

we have configured Jenkins - Editable Email Notification Templates for sending customized email after every build.

**What we did**:

1. Added script under `*Jenkins -> Manage Jenkins -> Editable Email Notification Templates-> Add New Template*`
   and then under `"Default Content"` section, we added default groovy scripts (for example: [groovy-html.template](https://github.com/jenkinsci/email-ext-plugin/blob/master/src/main/resources/hudson/plugins/emailext/templates/groovy-html.template) - Copy paste content). Save.
2. Now under project job, under *Post-build* section we selected same template
3. But when we receive emails, then email is coming without replacing environment variables.. like

> ```
>  " />     BUILD ${build.result} URL   ${rooturl}${build.url}
>
> Project:  ${project.name} Date:   ${it.timestampString} Duration: ${build.durationString} Cause:  ${cause.shortDescription}
> ```

**Problem**: Environment variable like "build.result", "build.url" etc are coming as variable name (instead of actual values). Are we missing something here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We need to specify into Default Content section as

```
${JELLY_SCRIPT,template="Jelly script name"}
```

and place script under JENKINS home "email-templates" folder.