# Single email notifications for multiple free style jobs in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-pipeline

**Objective:** 
To create multiple separate freestyle jobs for nightly automated builds, and send out single email notifications that includes the build status of all build jobs.

**Each jobs will build and use:** 
1) C++ solution project 
2) Perforce SCM

**Current Scenario:**
I've installed and used Editable Email Notification plugin and it works perfectly fine for a single job email notification. However, I'm looking for single email notifications for multiple jobs. And, don't know how as I'm new to Jenkins.

**Future Plan:**
To implement it using Jenkins pipelines (even though it might be long way to get there for me)

Please help or point me towards relevant online resources or suggest any alternatives.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Editable Email Notification plugin is the way to go.

It works on a per job basis. 1 email across many jobs is not supported currently.

Controlling the content of the email.  Have a look at this [plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/emailext-template) and this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43936651/jenkins-editable-email-notification-templates).

Here is how you use Email Notification plugin in pipeline with plenty of variable you can play around with:

```
emailext to: "${mailRecipients}",
             subject: "[Jenkins] ${jobName}",
             body: '''${SCRIPT, template="groovy-html.template"} ${BUILD_LOG, maxLines=8000, escapeHtml=true}''',
             mimeType: 'text/html',
             recipientProviders: [[$class: 'CulpritsRecipientProvider'],[$class: 'RequesterRecipientProvider']]
```

Comment: Thank you Andrew for the feedback.

Comment: My pleasure.  Would appreciate it if you could accept and upvote.